# Update NSMutableArray value based on index and key

Tags: ios, objective-c

In xCode I have filled an NSMutableArray with json data from my webserver.
I have 100 entries in the array - every entry has a name, address, website, etc....

Now I want to create a for-loop and update the name of every entry - but I don't know how to to this. I need something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.counter; i++)
{
 [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"] = "bla bla bla";
}
```

I know this example wont work but I think you know what I want to do when you see it ;)

Comment: Maybe you should actually describe what is in one array entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you read from disk/receive over the network tend to be immutable collections of immutable collections of immutable objects.

In order to be able to change things, you need to convert any collection you change to mutable form.

@NofelMahmood's post was a step in the right direction.

You likely have to change the entire branch of the "object graph" to mutable objects for every item you want to change. Or, if you are walking the entire array, just loop through the array, make a mutable copy of each item, and copy it to a new array. That solves the problem that you can't change (mutate) and array while enumerating through it:

```
//Create an empty mutable array to contain the changed dictionaries
NSMutableArray *mutableJSONArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: jsonArray.count];

//enumerate through the original array.
for (NSDictionary *aDictionary in jsonArray)
{ 
  //Make a mutable copy of each dictionary in the array.
  NSMutableDictionary *mDict = [aDictionary mutableCopy];

  //Replace the value at key @"key" with some new value @"new value"
  mDict[@"key"] = @"new value"; //Replace this part as needed

  [mutableJSONArray addObject; mDict];
}
```

Disclaimer: The code above likely contains minor typos, and probably won't compile at first. Cleaning it up is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to use the setObject For Key Method assuming that every entry in the jsonArray is an NSMutableDictionary object

```
for(id object in jsonArray)
    [object setObject:@"bla bla bla" forKey:@"name"];
```

#### UPDATE

```
for(id object in jsonArray)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableObject=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:object];
    [mutableObject setObject:@"bla bla bla" forKey:@"name"];
    [jsonArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[jsonArray indexOfObject:object] withObject:mutableObject];
}
```

Comment: Hi Nofel, xCode crashes on this loop with the following message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'. Any idea?

Comment: yes because that means the objects in jsonArray are of type NSDictionary and not NSMutableDictionary so they cannot be changed what you can do here is initialize a NSMutableDictionary object from the current object in the array change the value on it and replace it in the json array.